# Custom Drop Zone In Kendo For Angular Upload

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

In the non-angular specific versions of Kendo, we could have a custom drop zone that was configured with a CSS selector

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: "save",
        removeUrl: "remove",
        autoUpload: true
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif"]
    },
    success: onSuccess,
    showFileList: false,
    dropZone: ".dropZoneElement"
});
```

and where the HTML was just

```
<div class="dropZoneElement">
    <div class="textWrapper">
    <p><span>+</span>Add Image</p>
    <p class="dropImageHereText">Drop image here to upload</p>
</div>
```

Is this possible with Kendo UI For Angular?  The only reference I see to drop zone in the docs the message that can be displayed (and a brief reference in the changelogs).   If not, are there any workarounds?